Flutter: Show PDF and videos but prevent download
I'm planning to provide a mobile app and I'm looking for the best fit of a program language or Framework.
I want to provide/present PDF files and videos via an App and restrict usage to logged in users and prevent users from sharing the content.
I know there is no 100% safe way but I want to make it as hard as possible.
I've achieved this via Javascript and my servers Apache settings on a website but thinking of providing the content via an app.
Since I have no expirience with Flutter I want to ask if this is possible before learning a new Framework.
I couldn't find precise information on the web. I'm not asking for code, just for an estimate or maybe libraries that can do that in Dart.
Thank you,
Dirk

you can do it with flutter. You can read pdf and watch videos. Disable screenshot or screen recording somehow and I guess that's it.

@K J: I know. That's why I added the passage already in the post. ;-). But still I want to make it as hard as possible.

I recommend using React Native since you do not have prior experience with Flutter. Furthermore, React Native offers a broader library support for your task than Flutter. If you are aiming for a high-performance cross-platform application, then Flutter would be a suitable choice. However, for your specific use case, React Native seems to be the best option.

I'm not a professional programmer. I have much expirience with Python and Django. Good expirience with Javascript/Typenscript and Vue. Never used React but since React is JS it should work. Thanks for your recommendations

If you have a fairly good understanding of CSS, JavaScript, components, and hooks, you already know about 80% of React Native. However, this is not the case with Flutter, where you'll have to learn a completely new approach to UI creation.
